# 'wp-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, sass

I get the error 'wp-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS D:\Local\wpreactsite\app\public\wp-content\themes\brads-boilerplate-theme>

Here is a picture of package.json:
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBA1m.png)

Please help :)

I tried to start the project to get it watching me, and that I could update code to edit my wp site, that didnt work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Yeah Im new here so didnt knowed :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.